# How to remove duplicate rows from csv which is having key and value pairs?

Tags: java, csv

Sample test.csv is:

**2176=150MG    , 2178=I01  , 1011=1000210  , 1012=1,    1636=KG,    1638=Active**

2176=150MG  , 2178=I02  , 1011=1034669  , 1012=2    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active

**2176=200MG    , 2178=I03  , 1011=1034670  , 1012=3    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active**

**2176=150MG    , 2178=I01  , 1011=1000210  , 1012=1    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active**

2176=277MG  . 2178=I05  , 1011=1000535  , 1012=5    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active

**2176=200MG    , 2178=I03  , 1011=1034670  , 1012=3    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active**

Expected Result:

2176=150MG  , 2178=I01  , 1011=1000210  , 1012=1,    1636=KG,    1638=Active

2176=150MG  , 2178=I02  , 1011=1034669  , 1012=2    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active

2176=200MG  , 2178=I03  , 1011=1034670  , 1012=3    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active

2176=277MG  . 2178=I05  , 1011=1000535  , 1012=5    , 1636=KG   , 1638=Active

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could do this in pure bash if lines are identical. cat my_file.csv | sort | uniq

Comment: You will need to use, in some point, a `java.util.Set`... Either to store the rows as `String` or using a structure that match the format of the CSV

Comment: `Files.lines(csvPath).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` will get you the distinct lines. Write that back to the CSV and it will only contain unique records.